# Terraform: use each.value inside herodoc string

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, foreach, terraform, aws-event-bridge

I'm trying to deploy four lambdas with their triggers.
The goal is not to repeat code blocks, so I'm using for_each so that a cloudwatch_event_rule is created for each lambda (I create them in pairs, "start" and "stop").
Everything is working OK except for one thing, I can not place **each.value** inside a herodoc string. This value will be the ARN of the Medialive channel, and I need to use the correct one each time I create a new event rule.

Using a the variable with the ARN there will not do, since it will create two event "start" rules with the same ARN (same for the "stop" rules).
Can this be achieved?

My code (I added "///// THIS IS NOT WORKING" where the problem is, for clarity):

```
locals {

  lambda_start = {
    "Newrelic_Start_${var.channel_name_1}" = {string = "${var.channel_arn_1}"},
    "Newrelic_Start_${var.channel_name_2}" = {string = "${var.channel_arn_2}"},
  }
  lambda_stop = {
    "Newrelic_Stop_${var.channel_name_1}" = {string = "${var.channel_arn_1}"},
    "Newrelic_Stop_${var.channel_name_2}" = {string = "${var.channel_arn_2}"},
  }

}


resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_starts" {
  for_each      = local.lambda_start
  filename      = "Archive_Start.zip"
  function_name = each.key
  role          = "arn:aws:iam::${var.acc_id}:role/iam_for_lambda"
  handler       = "main.lambda_handler"


  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("Archive_Start.zip")

  runtime = "python3.9"

  architectures = ["x86_64"]
  timeout = 60
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_stops" {
  for_each      = local.lambda_stop
  filename      = "Archive_Stop.zip"
  function_name = each.key
  role          = "arn:aws:iam::${var.acc_id}:role/iam_for_lambda"
  handler       = "main.lambda_handler"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("Archive_Stop.zip")

  runtime = "python3.9"

  architectures = ["x86_64"]
  timeout = 60
}



# START 1
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "console-1" {
  for_each      = local.lambda_start
  name        = each.key
  event_pattern = <<EOF
{
  "source": ["aws.medialive"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["medialive.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["StartChannel"],
    "responseElements": {
      "arn": [{
        "prefix":"${each.value}"  ///// THIS IS NOT WORKING
      }]
    }
  }
}
EOF
}


resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "start" {
    rule = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.console-1[each.key].name
    target_id = "lambda_starts"
    for_each      = local.lambda_start
    arn = aws_lambda_function.lambda_starts[each.key].arn

}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_cloudwatch_to_call_lambda_starts" {
    statement_id = "AllowExecutionFromCloudWatch"
    action = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    for_each      = local.lambda_start
    function_name = aws_lambda_function.lambda_starts[each.key].function_name
    principal = "events.amazonaws.com"
    source_arn = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.console-1[each.key].arn
}


#STOP 1
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "console-stop-1" {
  for_each      = local.lambda_stop
  name        = each.key

  event_pattern = <<EOF
{
  "source": ["aws.medialive"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["medialive.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["StopChannel"],
    "responseElements": {
      "arn": [{
        "prefix": "${each.value}"  ///// THIS IS NOT WORKING 
      }]
    }
  }
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "stop" {
    rule = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.console-stop-1[each.key].name
    target_id = "lambda_stops"
    for_each      = local.lambda_stop
    arn = aws_lambda_function.lambda_stops[each.key].arn
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_cloudwatch_to_call_lambda_stops" {
    statement_id = "AllowExecutionFromCloudWatch"
    action = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    for_each      = local.lambda_stop
    function_name = aws_lambda_function.lambda_stops[each.key].function_name
    principal = "events.amazonaws.com"
    source_arn = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.console-stop-1[each.key].arn
}
```

This is the error I get from the code above:

```
│ Error: Invalid template interpolation value
│ 
│   on main.tf line 163, in resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "console-stop-1":
│  154:   event_pattern = <<EOF
│  155: {
│  156:   "source": ["aws.medialive"],
│  157:   "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
│  158:   "detail": {
│  159:     "eventSource": ["medialive.amazonaws.com"],
│  160:     "eventName": ["StopChannel"],
│  161:     "responseElements": {
│  162:       "arn": [{
│  163:         "prefix": "${each.value}"
│  164:       }]
│  165:     }
│  166:   }
│  167: }
│  168: EOF
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is object with 1 attribute "string"
│ 
│ Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `${each.value.string}`

Comment: How did I miss that lol. Thanks @jordanm!